# Best layout for detail views with heterogeneous rows

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've never seen a perfect layout strategy for detail views containing several heterogeneous rows, e.g., one row for name, one for address, one for email, one for age ..., just like the name editing view of Contacts, but more complex.

Obviously, it is a perfect "table" thing, and UITableView's group style is preferable to plain listing of rows (refer to the name editing view of Contacts).

However, UITableView is not flexible enough to handle the heterogeneity: the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method will be messed up with complex branches for different kinds of rows, like this:

```
switch (row) { 
    case kNameRowIndex: 
        nameField.text = name;
        break; 
    case kaddressRowIndex: 
        addressField.text = address;
        break; 
    case kEmailRowIndex: 
        emailField.text = email;
        break; 
    case kAgeRowIndex: 
        ageField.text = age;
        break;
    ...
    default:
}
```

This problem can be perfectly resolved if UITableView can be populated with static UITableViewCells in Interface Builder, which seems impossible, isn't it?

So what's best layout strategy for such detail views?

Comment: Can you explain why you feel that UITableView is not flexible enough, and will be "messed up"?

Comment: Otto,
I've added a very simple example which is a bloated switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all impossible to layout static UITableViewCells in interface builder.

In your view controller you can set IBOutlets for the different cells you want to use.  In the XIB file for your view controller, define UITableView cells that are not held in the main view and wire them to those outlets.  When the view loads you will have custom UITableViewCells you can return.

The only tricky part is that if they are of varying heights make sure to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath: so that you can return the frame heights for the static cells.

Comment: Good point. But what I want is not only to layout static UITableViewCells in IB, but also to layout a static UITableView in IB, i.e., to populate the static UITableView with those static UITableViewCells, so to get rid of UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Why?  What does it matter when all the data does is return static cells or details about them (like height)?

If you want to do that, what is the reason you are wanting to subclass UITableView instead of just adding components to a UIScrollView within IB?

Basically you cannot add data to a table in IB, but you can make a large scrollview and keep adding parts to it.  But you are really just better off defining the rows in a table because UITableView has a number of nice features with selections and headers and memory use.

Answer (score 0):

Make custom UITableViewCells for reusable sections of your layout and dequeue those when needed in *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:*. If you don't want to use UITableView, use  custom UIViews for each group of data you may need collecting, naming and organizing them appropriately: eg.  UIAddressDetailsView - country, area, city, street, number, etc, UINameDetailsView - first name, last name, initials, addressing formula, etc, UIPasswordAndEMailView...